# Mysql selecting date range from unixtime timestamp gives too many records

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp, date-range

I have a mysql query.

The idea is to select the records between a date range.  The dates are stored as unix timestamps.  With the query below, I end up with far more records than I should (out of the date range).

I have picked my brain and I cant see where the query is going wrong.  The other fields look correct, its just that I am out of the desired date range.

```
SELECT
        mdl_user_info_data.data,
        mdl_user.firstname, 
        mdl_user.lastname, 
        mdl_grade_grades.itemid, 
        mdl_grade_items.itemname,
        mdl_quiz.fcpd,
        mdl_user_info_data.id,
        mdl_grade_grades.timecreated AS DATE
        FROM mdl_grade_grades
        INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_grade_grades.userid = mdl_user.id
        INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items ON mdl_grade_grades.itemid = mdl_grade_items.id
        INNER JOIN mdl_quiz ON mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_quiz.course
        INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
        INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_course.id
        WHERE mdl_grade_grades.timecreated BETWEEN (FROM_UNIXTIME(1371704400) AND       FROM_UNIXTIME(1371790800))
        AND mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 1
        AND mdl_grade_items.itemname IS NOT NULL
        AND mdl_course.category = 27
        OR mdl_grade_items.itemname LIKE '%asa%'
        GROUP BY mdl_user.firstname, mdl_user.lastname, mdl_grade_grades.timecreated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OR` term negates some of the limits you built into the `WHERE` clause as it collects records that are *not* subject to your date selection.

Do you mean this?

```
    WHERE mdl_grade_grades.timecreated BETWEEN (FROM_UNIXTIME(1371704400) AND
    FROM_UNIXTIME(1371790800))
    AND mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 1
    AND mdl_grade_items.itemname IS NOT NULL
    AND 
    (
    mdl_course.category = 27
    OR 
    mdl_grade_items.itemname LIKE '%asa%'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

When a row satisfies the condition `OR mdl_grade_items.itemname LIKE '%asa%'` it will be selected.

Use `(` and `)` to group the conditions. For example:

```
WHERE mdl_grade_grades.timecreated BETWEEN (FROM_UNIXTIME(1371704400) AND       FROM_UNIXTIME(1371790800))
        AND mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 1
        AND mdl_grade_items.itemname IS NOT NULL
        AND (mdl_course.category = 27 OR mdl_grade_items.itemname LIKE '%asa%')
```